# How to stop Terminal from accessing AVFoundationCF framework every start up?

Tags: macos, terminal, avfoundation

Ever since I updated my OS from Sierra to High Sierra (and now, Mojave), I'm always greeted by the Terminal on every start up. It accesses AVFoundationCF and goes something like this:

```
[:~]$/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AVFoundationCF.framework/Versions/A/AVFoundationCF ; exit;
-bash: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AVFoundationCF.framework/Versions/A/AVFoundationCF: cannot execute binary file
logout
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.

[Process completed]
```

Have you encountered this? How do I prevent Terminal from doing this? Your help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Looks like you might have something odd in your Bash configuration. If you have a ~/.bash_profile and/or ~/.bashrc, what are their contents?

Comment: @NoahWitherspoon I only have the code below to change the colour:
`#Make ls colourful`
`#PS1="[\u@\h \W]\$ "  # Default`
`export PS1="\[\e[1;31m\][\[\e[0;31m\]\u\[\e[0m\]@\[\e[0;31m\]\h\[\e[0m\]:\[\e[0;35m\]\w\[\e[1;31m\]]\[\e[0m\]\$ "`
`export CLICOLOR=1`
`export LSCOLORS=ExFxBxDxCxegedabagacad`
`alias ls='ls -GFh'`

Also, I can't find the `.bashrc`